# Very slow AJAX response

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, codeigniter, ajax-request

I am working on PHP CodeIgniter. By clicking on customer name I call a JavaScript function `customerBasic` for some other purpose that also call `show_cs_info` that send AJAX call to controller as below.

AJAX function:

```
function customerBasic(customer_id,isConsumer, name )
 {
   document.getElementById('random').value = customer_id+"/"+name;
   $.ajax({
        url: site_url+"customer/connections/index/"+customer_id+"/"+0+"/"+isConsumer,
        type: 'post',
        success: function(data)
        { 

           show_cs_info(customer_id);
        }
     });

}
```

`show_cs_info` function:

```
function show_cs_info(id)
{
  $.ajax({
     url:site_url+"customer/customer/show_cs_info"+"/"+id+"/"+'no',
     type:'post',
     success:function(data)
     {
        $('#right_div').html(data);
     }
});
}
```

controller

```
 public function show_cs_info($id, $bit)
 {
    $id = urldecode($id);
    $bit = urldecode($bit);
    $this->load->model('customer_model');
    $data['val']= $this->customer_model->show_cs_info($id);
    $this->load->view('show_cust_info_view',$data);
 }
```

Model

```
 public function show_cs_info($id)
 {
        $this->db->where('customer_id',$id);
        $result = $this->db->get('customer_info');
        return $result->result();
 }
```

The AJAX call is taking 1.05s. How can I make it faster?

Comment: Put some logger to find where the time is taking more. Then try to optimize that part of the code.

Comment: Please tell me reasons why ajax response can slow?

Comment: It could be server side (test this separately) where your application takes time to respond or browser side javascript taking time, even too many ajax calls can be problem.

Comment: i am developing a big project that use ajax call for each link. i don't know why ajax call talking too much time some times it takes 2.05s. i check database queries working properly and also test ajax call separately it works fast! i couldn't find any solution of this problem.... please help me !!!

Comment: What exactly is slow? A network? Script execution?

Comment: jquery has no problem with ajax script execution, so ahmad, pls check the code on server

Comment: ZerKms and Kiddy you both can see the my complete script on top ajax function, controller function as well as model function also! then, what code i check on server ?

Comment: this may help you http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/195864/#922183

Answer (score -1):

Actually you need to check network connection if Database server is on another server and try to remove network latency.....
In other-case if you are working on local server and have web & DB server on same machine then check CPU Usage and Workload on MySQL it may be stuck due to some query......
Further upgrade your server & version of MySQL etc....